# Objects not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a private route component with renders a route, it returns `Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])` when I call a method with `async/await`. What do I need to change? There is a `checkTokenExpirationMiddlewareAdvertiser()` that verifies the role of a user and renders the right dashboard. It seems when I `async/await` for the user the promise doesn't resolve completely.

I have tried removing the `async` from the function but then i can't get the return value from the function.

```js
const AdvertiserPrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props => {
      console.log(rest)
      if (!loggedInUser())
        return (
          <Redirect
            to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }}
          />
        );
      return checkTokenExpirationMiddlewareAdvertiser(
        () => <Component {...props} />, // success component
        () => <AdvertiserError />, // failure component
      );
    }}
  />
);
```

```
export const checkTokenExpirationMiddlewareAdvertiser = async (success, fail) => {
  const { user } = await loggedInUser();
  console.log(user)
  if (user) {
    const { token } = user;
    if (jwtDecode(token).exp < Date.now() / 1000) {
      removeUser();
      return fail();
    }
    if (user.role !== 'advertiser') return fail();
    console.log('here');
    return success();
  }
  console.log("here")
  return fail();
};
```

Comment: You are calling `loggedInUser()` with await in `checkTokenExpirationMiddlewareAdvertiser` but without in `AdvertiserPrivateRoute`. Obviously, this is not your mistake but logically this does not make sense as well.

Comment: Yes..how do i call it with await in AdvertiserPrivateRoute?

Comment: You would either fire it inside a `Promise` and use `then` chaining or declare `AdvertiserPrivateRoute` as an async constant `const AdvertiserPrivateRoute = async ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => ...`

Comment: Hey thanks man, i just removed the `async` from the `checkToken` and it works well. seems the error was coming from a loooooong line of `async/await`. Thanks,

Comment: Would you mind marking something I will post here as answer (in a minute), as the answer, as I did actually solve your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of `async await` in combination with `loggedInUser()` is inconsistent.

1. Either remove it from `checkTokenExpirationMiddlewareAdvertiser`
2. Or add it to `AdvertiserPrivateRoute` (see below)

depending on whether `loggedInUser()` is an asynchronous function

```
const AdvertiserPrivateRoute = async ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props => {
      console.log(rest)
      const userLoggedIn = await loggedInUser();
      if (!userLoggedIn)
        return (
          <Redirect
            to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }}
          />
        );
      return checkTokenExpirationMiddlewareAdvertiser(
        () => <Component {...props} />, // success component
        () => <AdvertiserError />, // failure component
      );
    }}
  />
);
```